# How to use Lag with while to calculate the effectiveness of discount , SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate the effectiveness of a discount.

[image]

I want to update the last column as 'pozitive' if s_quantity increased and negative, if decreased. Neutral, if no change. I've written the code:

```
DECLARE @count AS INT

SET @count=1

WHILE @count< 316

BEGIN

IF product_id = @count

WHEN s_quantity > (LAG(s_quantity) OVER (ORDER BY product_id ASC, discount ASC))

UPDATE [SampleRetail].[sale].[Analiz] SET hesap_kitap = 'pozitif'

SET @count +=1

IF @count > 316
BREAK
ELSE
CONTINUE
END
```

Where do I make the mistake? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with the function `LAG()` in a SELECT.
(see the dbFiddle link below for the test schema.)

> ```
> SELECT
>   period,
>   sales, 
>   LAG(sales) OVER (ORDER BY period) p_1,
>   sales - LAG(sales) OVER (ORDER BY period) increase
> FROM sales
> ORDER BY period;
> ```

> ```
> period | sales |  p_1 | increase
> -----: | ----: | ---: | -------:
>      1 |   100 | null |     null
>      2 |   200 |  100 |      100
>      3 |   300 |  200 |      100
>      4 |   250 |  300 |      -50
>      5 |   500 |  250 |      250
>      6 |   500 |  500 |        0
> ```

> ```
> WITH sale as (
>   SELECT
>     period,
>     sales, 
>     LAG(sales) OVER (ORDER BY period) p_1
>   FROM sales)
>   
> SELECT 
>   period,
>   sales,
>   sales - p_1 increase,
>   CASE WHEN sales < p_1 THEN 'negative'
>        WHEN sales = p_1 THEN 'stable'
>        ELSE 'positive' END AS "change"
> FROM sale;
> ```

> ```
> period | sales | increase | change  
> -----: | ----: | -------: | :-------
>      1 |   100 |     null | positive
>      2 |   200 |      100 | positive
>      3 |   300 |      100 | positive
>      4 |   250 |      -50 | negative
>      5 |   500 |      250 | positive
>      6 |   500 |        0 | stable
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8b0d1e994a117f6c739473d954e1f31e)*